# How can i show wordcloud in html?

Tags: html, django-views, word-cloud

I made wordcloud function in view.py. There's no error, but it didn't show up in html.

I use {{ wordcloud }} to display it in template.

```html
<div style="margin-bottom:20px;"> {{ wordcloud }} </div>
&nbsp;<span id="clipboard-movie"></span><br />
```

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .models import ArticleData, Category, Keyword

import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from newspaper import Article# Newspaper
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import STOPWORDS

def word_cloud(text):
    whale_mask = np.array(Image.open("PK_t.png"))
    stopwords ={'은','입니다'}
    plt.figure(figsize = (20,5))
    #plt.imshow(whale_mask , cmap = plt.cm.gray , interpolation = 'bilinear')
    font_path = 'C:/Users/Jeong Suji/NanumBarunGothic.ttf'
    wc = WordCloud(font_path=font_path,background_color = 'white', max_words=2000, mask = whale_mask,
              stopwords = stopwords)
    wc= wc.generate(text)
    plt.figure(figsize= (10,5))
    plt.imshow(wc,interpolation= 'bilinear')
    plt.axis("off")
    image=plt.show()
    return image

def cloud_gen(request):
    text = ''
    for i in ArticleData.objects.all():
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            text += i.text
    wordcloud = word_cloud(text)
    return render(request, 'articles/index.html', {'wordcloud':wordcloud})

...
```

there's no error but wordcloud is not showed in html.